# Standard feeds for channels in youtube data api v3

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

This is a simple question which i'm not able to solve.
In YouTube data api v2 there was a standard feeds for channels such as 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/most_viewed?time=today&v=2&alt=json for **most viewed** and

for **most subscribed** is the

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/most_subscribed?time=this_week&v=2&alt=json

But I'm not getting **how to retrieve in YouTube data api v3 the standard feeds for channels**?

Even if someone helps out for url it's enough.

My Tries:-

[link1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)